# Pythonic way to construct a list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Is there a Pythonic way to to construct the following list (or similar):

```
N = 32000

my_list = []
l = 0 
while N // 2**l % 2 == 0:
     my_list.append(N // 2**l)
     l += 1
```

As far as I can see there's no way to break from the usual list construction syntax, `[i for i in range(10)]`, nor a way to specify an open-ended for-loop.

Comment: What's the desired behavior for any `N` and any divisor? Maybe there's an algebraic way to do it? For this particular case, you could do `my_list = [N / 2**i for i in range(int(numpy.log([N])/(2 * numpy.log([2]))))]` but that's ugly as hell.

Comment: This does not produce the same output. In any case, the example is not really important, I wanted the pythonic-idiom for constructing a list until a condition is met as the answer shows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could split this into two parts: the production of the calculations, and the handling of the end condition.

Producing an infinite sequence of calculations is straightforward:

```
from itertools import count, takewhile

N = 32000

nums = (N // 2**l for l in count())
```

Where [`count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) is like `range`, but no end is specified.

To cut it off, you can pair that with [`takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile), and negate the condition:

```
finite_nums = takewhile(lambda n: n % 2 == 0, nums)

>>> list(finite_nums)
[32000, 16000, 8000, 4000, 2000, 1000, 500, 250]
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides looking into what pythonic may mean to you, because I think that each of us has his own opinion of what pythonic is, you could simply rewrite your loop like so:

```
while not N // 2**l % 2 != 0:
     my_list.append(N // 2**l)
     l += 1
```

Or did you mean rewrite your list as a comprehension ?

Comment: Yes, I meant using list comprehension or other tools from Python. Sorry, I should have been clearer. To me, Pythonic means using features that are specific to Python rather that a generic programming language (like `while` loops).